# Converting mixed model output to percentage of change to match other model outputs (LME4/LMER)

Tags: r, regression, mixed-models

In my current dataset (40.000 persons), I have multi-year data on healthcare consumption per person (continuous cost data). I am applying multilevel models to this data to determine the effect of a certain intervention using R. I use the LME4 package with the lmer-function.

Since most of my cost data is skewed, I apply log-transformation to the data prior to running the models.  However, two cost categories are not skewed and therefore do not require log-transformation. This results in their model output not being a coefficient, but an estimated changes in total costs. Eventually, I want to be able to present all outcomes as percentages of change. However, taking the baseline mean costs of these non-transformed cost categories and divide it by my model estimates seems very inaccurate. Can someone help me on how to let LME4 calculate these non-transformed cost categories as percentage of chance instead of absolute costs in order to match the output of models with log-transformed data?

Below is an example of model output without any control variables for log-transformed costs (with some model terms in Dutch). The variable of interest is "DementieNet3":

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: zorgkosten2 ~ factor(DementieNet3) + (1 | zcl_id) + (1 | huisarts_agb)
   Data: zorgkosten_huisarts
Control: lmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 2e+05))

REML criterion at convergence: 409486

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.2770 -0.4942  0.1248  0.6296  3.4145 

Random effects:
 Groups       Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 zcl_id       (Intercept) 0.2672   0.5170  
 huisarts_agb (Intercept) 0.0479   0.2189  
 Residual                 0.6547   0.8091  
Number of obs: 153636, groups:  zcl_id, 38267; huisarts_agb, 6170

Fixed effects:
                      Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)           4.407173   0.004952 889.934
**factor(DementieNet3)1 0.021745   0.038981   0.558**

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr)
fctr(DmN3)1 -0.046
```

Using "exp [coefficient]" transforms the model estimate to the percentage of change in costs that I present in my article. However, two cost categories are not skewed and therefore do not require log-transformation. This results in their model output not being a coefficient as shown above, but an estimated changes in total costs (see below).

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: totale_zorgkosten ~ factor(DementieNet3) + (1 | zcl_id) + (1 |      huisarts_agb)
   Data: zorgkosten_totaal_incl_WLZ
Control: lmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 2e+05))

REML criterion at convergence: 423621.4

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.1657 -0.7326  0.0733  0.6947  6.4623 

Random effects:
 Groups       Name        Variance  Std.Dev.
 zcl_id       (Intercept) 235701044 15353   
 huisarts_agb (Intercept)   8221947  2867   
 Residual                 589271369 24275   
Number of obs: 18164, groups:  zcl_id, 9378; huisarts_agb, 1610

Fixed effects:
                      Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)            52140.7      267.6 194.813
**factor(DementieNet3)1    450.8     1918.7   0.235**

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr)
fctr(DmN3)1 -0.122
```

Can someone help me on how to let LME4 calculate these non-transformed cost categories as percentage of chance instead of absolute costs in order to match the output of models with log-transformed data?